# Does anybody know Django-easy map support more than one addresses?

Tags: django

I want to create a map show more than one addresses on a map. Have tried django-easy map, it works well for only one address. Have not found hwo to feed more than one addresses to it. Does anybody know how?

Thanks,

Django easy-map:http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-maps

Comment: I don´t think [look](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-easy-maps/src/7b15574a8580/easy_maps/templates/easy_maps/map.html) maybe this can help you to display more than one addresses  in one map . store your geodata with [django-geoposition](http://django-geoposition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and print it with javascript an django-template [my-solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827613/placing-markers-on-google-map-with-django/13921268#13921268)